# Knockout Mapping - how to handle creation of new objects?

Tags: knockout.js

In my application, I have a list of `Books` that come from the server.

I use `ko.mapping` to generate observable properties for each `Book` that hits the client from my `GetBooks` AJAX call.

This is working great - mapping is taking care of a lot of the "noise" that I would have to handle manually.

But say I want to create a new `Book`.  I've been getting into the habit of creating objects with empty properties for all of my models - so for `book`, I have something like this:

```
var defaultBook = {
   title: null,
   price: null,
   genre: null,
   pages: null
}
```

Then, when I create a new `Book`, I just `ko.mapping.fromJS(defaultBook)` and `applyBindings` to my `add` form.

Is this the standard approach to new object creation - keeping a collection of empty models somewhere on the client?  I feel like this is a noobish question but just want to make sure I'm not missing out on a better, more standard pattern.  It strikes me as painful because this means that if I change a property name on the server, I need to change it on my client model definition as well... but maybe this is unavoidable.

Comment: What server do you have? I think I have an answer for .NET, but not sure you need it :)

Comment: Its a client side KO mapping problem

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin it is .NET :)

Comment: I've added my answer. @Anders - your answer is perfect, but doesn't answer TO problem - "this means that if I change a property name on the server, I need to change it on my client"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem yesterday too

```
MyApp.PersonNameEditViewModel = MyApp.define({
    init: function (data) {
        var fields = {
            nameTypeId: null,
            personNameId: null, 
            personId: null,
            firstname: "",
            prefix: "",
            surname: ""
        }

        this.nameTypeId = null;
        this.personNameId = null;
        this.firstname = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

        ko.utils.extend(fields, data);
        ko.mapping.fromJS(fields, {}, this);

        this.name = ko.computed(this.getName, this);
        this.title = this.name;
        this.new = this.personNameId === null;
    },
    prototype: {
        getName: function () {
            var parts = [this.surname(), this.firstname(), this.prefix()];
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(parts, function(part) {
                return part != "";
            }).join(", ") || "Untitled";
        }
    }
});
```

I am extending the fields object with data sent into the constructor

```
ko.utils.extend(fields, data);
```

This way it can be used both for new added rows or existing ones from backend. I use it like this from the mapping plugin

```
var mapping = {
    personNames: {
        create: function (options) {
            return new MyApp.PersonNameEditViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
```

And when creating new row

```
newAlternativname: function () {
    new MyApp.DetailsEditViewModel(new MyApp.PersonNameEditViewModel({ personId: this.personId(), nameTypeId: MyApp.NameTypes.AlternativeName }), true, this.personNames).modal();
}
```

As you can see I send in some stuff as data but not all when adding a new row, `ko.utils.extend` makes sure that the missing fields are added and mapped through `ko.mapping.fromJS`

Answer (score 0):

Although @Anders's answer is good and correct (you should do this on client side), but it only concerns client side and TO asked about model changes on server side. Here is what I did in similar situation. I created an extension method for StringBuilder which is used to build javascript variables:

```
public static class ScriptBuilder
{
    public static StringBuilder BuildGlobalVariable(this StringBuilder sb, string name, object value)
    {
        return sb.AppendFormat("var {0} = {1};", name, 
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            }));
    }
}
```

CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() is here only to make properties names in lower case, to follow javascript notation. Then in my JsModelsController I have this method:

```
public class JsModelsController : Controller
{
    public JavaScriptResult ServerModels()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        return sb.BuildGlobalVariable("Book", new Book()).ToString();
    }
}
```

Where Book is:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public int? Pages { get; set; }
}
```

So now you just need to add a script tag somewhere in your _Layout.cshtml page like this:

```
<script src="JsModels/ServerModels"></script>
```

And hopefully it should load the following script on your page:

var Book = {"title":null,"price":null,"genre":null,"pages":null};

P.S. I know that it's a bad practise to create global JS objects, so you could just accumulate all your server models to one JS global object like this:

```
return sb.BuildGlobalVariable("ServerModels", new 
{
    Book = new Book(),
    Person = new Person()
}).ToString();
```

Where Person is another server class. This is not perfect either, but allows to have only one global JS variable with all server models in it.

Comment: You still need to update your bindings,  computed etc,  so I can't really see this help a lot?

Comment: This helps to avoid hardcoding server object models to javascript code (see "fields" object in your answer). Solution is the combination of both answers - mine is for server side, yours is for client side (instead of "fields" TO could use ServerModels.fields now). But since TO asked about changes in server object fields, I think my answer is more accurate :) Although I completely support your solution as well!